# Getting date components from UIDatepicker

Tags: swift, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker (date type), which asks user to select his/her date of birth.

How do I get date components of the date of birth. Components (Day, Month, Year).

I can get NSDate from Datepicker and then use calendar to get the components. But this seems like round-about way. Datepicker already makes an assumption of Gregorian calendar.

Can I get components directly from Datepicker without having to go through NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through a NSCalender to get the components but it can be the one that the NSDatePicker is already using:

```
let components = datePicker.calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: datePicker.date)
let day = components.day
let month = components.month
let year = components.year
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for SWIFT 5**

```
// Get date picker data
let components = datePicker.calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year],
                                                    from: datePicker.date)
let day = components.day
let month = components.month
let year = components.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSCalendar component method to extract any component you would like from the date pickers date. Take a look at the example below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
        datePicker.minimumDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -120, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "dateChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func dateChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
        print(sender.date.year)
        print(sender.date.month)
        print(sender.date.day)
        print(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: sender.date, toDate: NSDate(), options: []).year)
    }
}

extension NSDate {
    var day: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day,   fromDate: self)
    }
    var month: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Month, fromDate: self)
    }
    var year: Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Year,  fromDate: self)
    }
}
```